# Does Java EE not have text fields in scriptlets?

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee

So I have been wandering around the web for some time looking for this answer. Is there no way of having text fields in java scriptlets for a JSP? I know that in C# you can have

```
@Html.TextField();
```

And that will create a text field for you to use as C# code.

Why I would like this, is that I am grabbing a session and checking to see if the user attribute has a user name stored. If it does I don't want it to display the username textbox. Although from what I can tell I can't do that with java scriptlets.

```
<%if(session.getAttribute("user") == null) %>
Username: <input type="text" name="name"><br/>
```

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Of course you can. You *shouldn't* [use scriptlets], but you can. Normally this kind of functionality would be wrapped up in a custom tag, or by simply using JSTL to implement the `if`.

Comment: I haven't heard of JSTL until now. I will look into that and custom tags. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, but it's better to use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html)   and [Expression language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL3.html)
 instead of scriptlets. It tend to complicate maintenance  for JSP-pages.

You can set a scoped variable on the JSP page. In this manner:

```
<c:set var="myVariable" scope="page" value="expression"/>
```

Your situation can be easily solved with the help of JSTL with EL:

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope.user eq null}">
   <c:out value="Username: ${myVariable}" />
</c:if>
```

If you have a more complex logic then it makes sense to create a [custom tags](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/taglib/quickstart.html).

Comment: When using this method I end up getting a Jasper Exception:
**According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute test does not accept any expressions**

Comment: You're using the outdated jar-files. Check version of JSTL taglib you use. It should be at least 1.1, so you should have (note the URI): `<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` Instead of `http://java.sun.com/jstl/core`.

Comment: If this does not work try using this directive `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>` which basically tells jsp to evaluate EL.

Comment: In extreme case you can calculate the value of the your expression in advance in the additional tag `<c:set var="resultExpression" scope="page" value="${theExpression}"/>`. And then only use it: `<c:if test="resultExpression">`. This will also prevent this exception